# jQuery - wait for all nested ajax and each calls to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I can't seem to get this bit of JavaScript to run to completion before continuing on. There's an each inside of an ajax, which itself is inside of an each inside of an ajax.

Each time I load this in Chrome (and set a breakpoint where my comment says "I don't want this to happen until..."), it gets to my breakpoint before my htmlDivs collection has anything in it. After continuing, the htmlDivs collection always gets filled, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong in my attempt to use promises and .done() below.

This is best illustrated by code:

```
var htmlDivs = {};

function SelectTopLevelThingFromPage(id) {
    SetupHtmlDivs(id).done(
        function () {
            // I don't want this to happen until SetupHtmlDivs() completes
            // (including all nested $.each and $.ajax)
            var keys = Object.keys(htmlDivs);
            // Append the htmlDivs in a specific sorted order
        }
    );
}

function SetupHtmlDivs(id) {
    var promises = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/GetSecondLevelThingsFromTopLevelId" + id,
        method: "get",
        success: function (SecondLevelThings) {
            $.each(SecondLevelThings, function (i, SecondLevelThing) {
                var promise = SetupHtmlForOneThing(SecondLevelThing);
                promises.push(promise);
            });
        }
    });

    return $.when.apply($, promises).promise();
}

function SetupHtmlForOneThing(SecondLevelThing) {
    var promises = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/SecondLevelThing/" + SecondLevelThing.id + "/Environments",
        method: "get",
        success: function (Environments) {
            $.each(Environments, function (k, env) {
                var def = new $.Deferred();
                promises.push(def);
                htmlDivs[SecondLevelThing.id + "-" + env] = SecondLevelThing;
                def.resolve();
            });
        }
    });

    return $.when.apply($, promises).promise();
}
```

Comment: I suspect it is because the `promises` array is empty by the time the code gets to the bottom of `SetupHtmlDivs` as the first `ajax` call hasn't fired yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var htmlDivs = {};

function SelectTopLevelThingFromPage(id) {
    SetupHtmlDivs(id).done(
        function () {
            // I don't want this to happen until SetupHtmlDivs() completes
            // (including all nested $.each and $.ajax)
            var keys = Object.keys(htmlDivs);
            // Append the htmlDivs in a specific sorted order
        }
    );
}

function SetupHtmlDivs(id) {

    var finalPromise = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/GetSecondLevelThingsFromTopLevelId" + id,
        method: "get",
        success: function (SecondLevelThings) {
            var promises = [];
            $.each(SecondLevelThings, function (i, SecondLevelThing) {
                var promise = SetupHtmlForOneThing(SecondLevelThing);
                promises.push(promise);
            });

            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
                finalPromise.resolve();
            });
        }
    });

    return finalPromise;
}

function SetupHtmlForOneThing(SecondLevelThing) {
    var innerPromise = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/SecondLevelThing/" + SecondLevelThing.id + "/Environments",
        method: "get",
        success: function (Environments) {
            $.each(Environments, function (k, env) {
                htmlDivs[SecondLevelThing.id + "-" + env] = SecondLevelThing;
            });
            innerPromise.resolve();
        }
    });

    return innerPromise;
}
```

The big changes are:

- The inner function, `SetupHtmlForOneThing`, didn't need promises within the ajax call since that is a non-ajax operation in the `success` callback. It need only resolve the singular promise offered by itself.
- The outer function, `SetupHtmlDivs`, needed only one promise which gets resolved when all of the generated inner promises are complete.